# IpSubnet and CIDR Deprecated in Netty 4

Tags: netty

I'm upgrading from Netty 3 to Netty 4 and am trying to track down the history/intent of IpCubnet and CIDR classes being deprecated.

I could not find any mention in release notes. I found a commit removed the classes - "Remove the codecs and handlers that can't make it on time for 4.0.0.A1"

https://github.com/netty/netty/commit/45f19d02ff9a9e2c72e4d95e38c5d7f73960fe57

Is this functionality deprecated for some reason? Or has it just not made it's way back in to Netty 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These classes were rewritten and replaced. Now you may use alternatives like `AbstractRemoteAddressFilter`, `UniqueIpFilter`, `RuleBasedIpFilter`, `IpSubnetFilterRule`, etc.

Have a look into [io.netty.handler.ipfilter](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/ipfilter) package.